# androidManifest activity android:excludeFromRecents

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am using following code to open an activity as a popup window using

```
<activity android:name=".RadioButtonExample" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true"/>
```

But `excludeFromRecents` is not working. If user clicks back button the popup window shows while retrieving back to main menu.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use `android:noHistory="true"`

> Whether or not the activity should be removed from the activity stack
>   and finished (its finish() method called) when the user navigates away
>   from it and it's no longer visible on screen — "true" if it should be
>   finished, and "false" if not. The default value is "false". A value of
>   "true" means that the activity will not leave a historical trace. It
>   will not remain in the activity stack for the task, so the user will
>   not be able to return to it.